# XSLT: sort and limit nested nodes

Tags: sorting, limit, xslt-1.0

**XML:**

```
<node>
  <node date="01-01-2002">Node</node>
  <node date="01-01-2005">Node</node>
  <node date="01-01-2001">Node</node>
  <node date="01-01-2003">Node</node>
  <node date="01-01-2006">Node</node>
  <node>
    <node date="01-01-2000">Node</node>
    <node date="01-01-2007">Node</node>
  </node>
  <node date="01-01-2004">Node</node>
</node>
```

**Problem:**
I need to sort by date AND take a limited number of sorted nodes. Need to be able to traverse any number of levels.

**Required result:**

```
<p>01-01-2000</p>
<p>01-01-2001</p>
<p>01-01-2002</p>
<p>01-01-2003</p>
<p>01-01-2004</p>
```

**Assumptions:**
For sorting by date I use c# extension method that returns time stamp:

```
<xsl:sort select="cs:formatDate(@date)" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
```

Limit to 5 oldest nodes.
Order: ascending
XSLT 1.0

**EDIT:**
As requested this is where i got so far:
I can do sorting and limiting for not nested nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="node">

  <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
    <xsl:sort select="cs:formatDate(@date,'dd-MM-yyyy','timestamp')" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
    <xsl:with-param name="limit" select="5"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>


</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node[@date]">
  <xsl:param name="limit" />
  <xsl:if test="position() &lt; $limit+1">
    <h5><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></h5>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Or when I try to apply for nested as below, I get nested nodes sorted in isolation, and I cannot limit them in same way anymore:

```
<xsl:template match="*">


    <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@date]">
      <xsl:sort select="cs:formatDate(@date,'dd-MM-yyyy','timestamp')" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node[not(@date)]">
    </xsl:apply-templates>


</xsl:template>



<xsl:template match="node[@date]">
  <h5><xsl:value-of select="@date"/></h5>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node[not(@date)]">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node[@date]">
    <xsl:sort select="cs:formatDate(@date,'dd-MM-yyyy','timestamp')" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
  </xsl:apply-templates>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node[not(@date)]">
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

**EDIT:**

I thought it is obvious, but probably not: I need sort to be applied before the limit. E.g: "get oldest five" and NOT:"get first five nodes from xml and then sort them"

Comment: And what is your question? (Please provide enough code to actually run something while you edit your question.)

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig Question is described by "problem" and "required result" I will update with where I got so far.

Comment: @ChristopherCreutzig I have updated question with where I got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@date]">
        <xsl:sort select="concat(substring-after(substring-after(@date,'-'),'-'),substring-before(substring-after(@date,'-'),'-'),substring-before(@date,'-'))" order="ascending" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:with-param name="start" select="1"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="end" select="5"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="node">
    <xsl:param name="start" />
    <xsl:param name="end" />
    <xsl:if test="position() &gt;= $start and position() &lt;= $end">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@date"/>
        </p>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: by '<foreach' I believe you meant '<xsl:for-each' ?. I know my Sort works. Question is how can I apply it to nested nodes.

Comment: @SergejPopov I editted my answer. The foreach was bad because it doesn't already take the sorted position() into account

Comment: Have you tested the solution? It has multiple issues..
1: Abbreviated step '.' cannot be followed by a predicate. (May be its just the processor that I use..)
2: Hosting nodes don't have date attribute, hence error
3: even when you sort out above 2 you will get nested nodes sorted in isolation, not all together

Comment: yes, tested it. ... And you dont even need a cs extenstion. See my new edit. Try this new code as I also moved the `[@node]` part to the match.

Comment: @SergejPopov Hope you understand what is in it. Don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Yes it all makes sense, thanks. and +1 for date sort without extension method.